# Does Couchbase have the concept "required field"?

Tags: couchbase

Is it possible in Couchbase to declare a rule that the record cannot be saved if a particular field is null?  I am actively researching at this very moment, but a quick answer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it does not. Couchbase does not today interrogate the data you put into it to the level you are asking about. So what you are asking for would have to be application level logic.